# Pointing a Sub-domain to a sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

Using Laravel I'm generating php pages in to a sub-directory called `webpage`. I want to allow users to access pages using sub-domain. For example, I've generated a file `whoami.php` into `webpage` directory. If people try to access `whoami.domain.com`, he can see the `whoami.php`. I've crated an `index.php` inside `webpage` which can extract alias and show the file. The think I need is to pass the subdomain to index.php file without redirecting. I wrote htaccess as follow

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #sub domain custom part
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/webpage/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But I'm redirecting into `http://domain.com/webpage/whoami`.

I tried to make my requirements clearly and pasted what I tried. Can you please help me to figure out a way?

**EDIT 1**
Based on @Starkeen's answer I tried the following code an now in a redirect loop (`http://whoami.domain.com/webpage/whoami/webpage/whoami/......`).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

        #sub domain
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webpage/%1/$1 [L,NC,R]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a every simple solution. As I'm using Laravel and that already use an `index.php` as bootstrap, I wrote some PHP codes there to achieve my goal. You guys can use if needed. And please advice me if my solution isn't good enough. Thanks

**My Solution**

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$link = str_replace(array('http://', 'https://', 'www.'), '', $link);

$splitted = explode(".", $link);

if($splitted[0] != 'domain'){
    $file_name = $splitted[0].'.php';
    $file_loc = 'webpage/'.$file_name;

    if(file_exists($file_loc)) {
        include($file_loc);
    } else {
        header('Location: http://domain.com/not-found');
    }

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect subdomain to a subfolder, You probably need to put the following right after the "RewriteEngine On" line :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub)\.domain\.com$ 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webpage/%1/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: I tried your solution an now in a redirect loop. I've updated the question with code what I did. Can you please check.

Thanks